# How do I collapse certain strings with a specific pattern from a text?

Tags: r

I have some strings of text (example below actual text is an entire book). As you can see each string was split at a period or question mark.

```
   [1]"I am a Mr."
   [2]"asking for help."
   [3]"Can you help?"
   [4]"Thank you ms."
   [5]"or mr."
```

I want to collapse where the string ends with an abbreviation like mr., mrs. so the end result would be the desired output below.

```
    [1]"I am a Mr. asking for help."
    [2]"Can you help?"
    [3]"Thank you ms. or mr."
```

I already created a vector (called abbr) containing all my abbreviations in the following format:

```
> abbr
[1] "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Ave|Blvd|Rd|Mt|Capt|Maj"
```

but I can't figure out how to use it in paste function to collapse. I have also tried using gsub (didn't work) to replace \n following abbreviation with a period with a space like this:

```
lines<-gsub('(?<=abbr\\.\\n)(?=[A-Z])', ' ', lines, perl=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `strsplit`, with the following logic
* Split on empty space
* Space preceded by punctuation
* Punctuation NOT preceded by vector of abbreviations

I put the string into 1 character vector like so:

```
lines2 <- paste(lines, collapse = ' ')
lines2
[1] "I am a Mr. asking for help. Can you help? Thank you ms. or mr."
```

Heres how to accomplish that with regex. Importantly, your attempt used "abbr" in quotes in a way that wont find the vector you define, you have to include it with a `paste`. I also added "mr" and "ms" to `abbr`. I include several lines that build up the ideas. I use look-behinds, you can learn more [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
# Split on punctuation
strsplit(lines2, "[[:punct:]]", perl = T)

# Split on punctuation, not preceded by abbr
strsplit(lines2, paste("(?<!",abbr,")[[:punct:]]"), perl = T)

# Split on space after punctuation, not preceded by abbr
strsplit(lines2, paste("(?<=(?<!", abbr,")[[:punct:]])[[:space:]]"), perl = T)

[[1]]
[1] "I am a Mr. asking for help." "Can you help?"              
[3] "Thank you ms. or mr."
```

Comment: We were working on it at the same time, you just beat me. Nice solution

Comment: Thanks your solution worked. Do you know how I might make abbr case insensitive.  So that it could detect mr. even if only Mr. is in the vector. or alternatively how I could uppercase the first letter of all the abbreviations in my vector?

Comment: Either `tolower` or `tools::toTitleCase`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)

lines <- c("I am a Mr.", "asking for help.", "Can you help?", "Thank you ms.", "or mr.")
abbr <- "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Ave|Blvd|Rd|Mt|Capt|Maj"

paste(lines, collapse = " ") %>%
  str_split(paste0("(?<=(?<!",abbr,"|", tolower(abbr),")\\.|\\?)\\s")) %>%
  unlist()
#> [1] "I am a Mr. asking for help." "Can you help?"              
#> [3] "Thank you ms. or mr."
```

First I undo the original spllit to get one big string, then I split the text by a space that is preceded by a question mark or a period, but only if the period is not preceded by an abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hacky, but this works:

```r
texts <- c("I am a Mr.", "asking for help.", "Can you help?", "Thank you ms.", "or mr.")
abbr <- "Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|Ave|Blvd|Rd|Mt|Capt|Maj"
texts2 <- c()
to_skip <- c()
for (i in seq_along(texts)) {
  if (i %in% to_skip) next
  if (grepl(abbr, texts[i], ignore.case = TRUE)) {
    texts2[i] <- paste(texts[i], texts[i+1], collapse = " ")
    to_skip <- c(to_skip, i+1)
  } else {
    texts2[i] <- texts[i]
  }
}
texts2[!is.na(texts2)]
#> [1] "I am a Mr. asking for help." "Can you help?"              
#> [3] "Thank you ms. or mr."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>